# div does not get centered using margin: auto in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to get a  centered in the space that is left empty by a sidebar. This is how I'd like it to look like:

[image]

I actually managed to make this work OK for most browsers using `margin: auto` for the `div` in question, while setting `overflow: hidden`:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pferreir/bc6q5/)

**CSS**

```
#header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #224444;
    color: #fff;
}

#container div {
    padding: 1em;
}

#content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        PAGE HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="content">
       Centered Content
        (Works everywhere but on IE9)
    </div>
</div>
```

However, it does not work with IE9. It is strange as IE8 works OK!

I am running out of ideas, so I thought that maybe someone knows what is going on? The trick seems to work perfectly everywhere else.

**NOTE**: Please note that the content `div` should be flexible as it is in the demo. As the available space decreases, it should change size and squeeze in.

Comment: If you want the centered content to have a variable width, that pretty much rules out using `margin: auto;`

Comment: @MattCoughlin IE8 and all modern browsers besides IE9 seem to disagree, though :/

Comment: hmmm... once the `max-width` kicks in, it must be functioning as an implicit fixed width, so that `margin: auto` has a fixed width to work with (except in IE9, I guess).

Comment: There is a rather old solution for centering auto-width floats in a container: http://www.artlebedev.com/tools/technogrette/html/align-center/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Isolate the centering from the floating

This affects IE9/10.

It works fine if the floated element is removed, or if `width` is used instead of `max-width`. The presence of floated content, combined with the use of `margin:auto` and `max-width` instead of `width`, appears to be confusing IE9+.

To fix this, put the centered content in a wrapper div, so that the centering of the content can be separated from the floating of the sidebar. In other words, too much is happening layout-wise in a single div, more than IE9+ can handle. So split up the `#content` div into two separate divs.

```css
#header {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #224444;
    color: #fff;
}

#content-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #aaa;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        PAGE HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            Centered Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This tested fine in IE7/8/9/10. On a side note, because a wrapper div was added, the `padding: 1em;` now has to be added to each element individually.

Comment: Seconding this.  IE 8, and latest Firefox, Safari, Chrome seem to handle absolute positioning, max-width and margin-auto in the same div.  IE 9, 10 and 11 do not- they'll position it left.  I confirmed that splitting the "absoluting" and the max-width/margining works well for all browsers including IE 9, 10 11.  Thanks Matt =)

Answer (score 3):

IE is notorious for not working without proper doctypes.

Try adding the HTML5 one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floats are a tricky business. Strictly speaking, they're only supposed to affect the inline content that flows around them, so margins acts like the floats aren't even there.

Try this instead:

```
#container {text-align:center}
#content {display:inline-block;text-align:left}
```

This should make the content box act like an inline element, and therefore appear centered in the space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works (`#content` gets centered), but it creates another problem which is even worse: the content will not adapt to the available space. As you decrease the window size, you'll see that `#content` will eventually move down.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remeber I've always problems with `margin:0 auto` because I didn't specify `width` property. 
So everytime you want use `margin:auto` you propably should write this:

```
#content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:500px;
}
```

or in percentage:

```
#content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:30%;
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to create flexible layout please take a look to [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and fluid grids.

Comment: Thanks, I had already thought of that, but I don't want the content width to be fixed. I just want it to have a maximum, but to then adapt to whatever space is available.